# highcharts.js add mouseOver function or hover states (implement breaks chart?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

After integrating hoverstates or mouseOver function, chart just breaks.. **any suggestions on how to successfully implement color hover state?** *(is it possible to have a different color hover state per each of 3 sections, so 3?)*

```
   series: [{
        point: {

        events: {
            click: function(e) {
                location.href = e.point.url;
                e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            mouseOver: function () { // hover attempt added here?
                this.options.oldColor = this.color;
                this.graphic.attr("fill", "black");
            },
            mouseOut: function () {
                this.graphic.attr("fill", this.options.oldColor);
                }
            } // hover attempt with this snippet broke chart?

        },

        innerSize: '30%',
        data: [
            {name: 'Shop', y: 10, url: '/#pie2'},
            {name: 'Buy', y: 10,  url: '/#pie3'},
            {name: 'Own', y: 10,  url: '/#pie4'}
        ]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your events object has a few mismatching parentheses that would cause javascript errors, I would suggest keeping an eye on the console for js errors all times.

To accomplish hover effect, you could simply define the [hover state options](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.states.hover) in your series or plotOptions

```
marker: {
    states: {
        hover: {
            fillColor: '#000'
        }
    }
}
```

[Handling hover @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/x1pc2rh9/)

If you don't want the same hover effect across all points and have some specific logic, you could use the [mouseOver](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver) and [mouseOut](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOut) events like you were trying. Note that it may feel sluggish if not implemented well.

```
events: {
    mouseOver: function () {
        this.update({
            color: '#000'
        });
    },
    mouseOut: function () {
        this.update({
            color: this.series.color
        });
    }
}
```

[Custom hover @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/L71g2kes/)